# System.FormatException Error in sending a e-mail

Tags: c#, exception

Error:An exception of type 'System.Format Exception' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code.Additional information: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

I am trying to send a mail but the code is giving an exception System.Format Exception.I am trying to send a mail after a certain time period.  here is the code

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace esaote
{
    public partial class user : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ASHISH;Initial Catalog=esaote;Integrated Security=True");

            TextBox6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            TextBox7.Text = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.00).ToShortDateString();
            maildate();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string q = "insert into info(c_name,c_address, machine, s_version, email,i_date,due_date) values(@c_name, @c_address, @machine, @s_version, @email, @i_date,@due_date)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_name", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_address", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_version", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_date",Convert.ToDateTime( TextBox6.Text ));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@due_date",Convert.ToDateTime( TextBox7.Text));
            //string due_date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).ToShortDateString();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script languge='javascript'>alert('data inserted');</script>");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.Write(exp.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }

        public void maildate()
        {
            SqlConnection con =new  SqlConnection("Data Source=ASHISH;Initial Catalog=esaote;Integrated Security=True");
            string s = "select * from info";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++ )
            {
                DateTime id = Convert.ToDateTime( ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["i_date"]);
                DateTime pd = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["due_date"]);

                double diff = (pd - id).TotalDays;
                if(diff>=1)
                {
                    string email = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["email"]);
                    string customer = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["c_name"]);
                    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(" Service Call","ashishbhatt1501@gmailcom"))
                     {
                        // mm.Body = "your sevice for '" + customer + "' are due.";

                         mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
                         SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                         smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                         smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                         NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("ashishbhatt1501@gmail.com", "062621562a");
                         smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                         smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                         smtp.Port = 587;
                         try
                            {
                             smtp.Send(mm);
                             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
                            }
                            catch (Exception exp) { Console.Write("helllo" + exp); }
                       }
                  }
                }
            }

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in the [`MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is the **from** address, but you seem to be using

```
MailMessage(" Service Call",
```

Change this to the from address you want to use.

Also, where are you setting the `To`? You might be better off constructing the `MailMessage` and setting these properties in the `Using` statement...

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
{
  mm.from = "ashishbhatt1501@gmailcom";
  mm.to = email; //I'm assuming email from your code.
  mm.subject = "Service Call"; //again, this is just an assumption
  ...
}
```

**Side Note:**
Just thought I'd mention this as a side note; some of the code you have above should be refactored:

- The connections strings can be moved into a `config` file
- The mail sending code could be moved into a new class, and expose a `SendMail` method to help minimize code replication
- You could wrap the `Insert` code into a `DataHelper` class.

Basically, I'm saying you can move a lot of this code outside of the code-behind file.